# SystemTap script to analyze the cache behavior of functions

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, profiling, perf, systemtap

I would like to profile the cache behavior of a kernel module with SystemTap (#cache references, #cache misses, etc). There is an example script online which shows how SystemTap can be used to read the perf events and counters, including cache-related ones: 
https://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/profiling/perf.stp

This sample script works by default for a process:

```
probe perf.hw.cache_references.process("/usr/bin/find").counter("find_insns") {}
```

I replaced the `process` keyword with `module` and the path to the executable with the name of my kernel module:

```
probe perf.hw.cache_references.module(MODULE_NAME).counter("find_insns") {}
```

I'm pretty sure that my module has the debug info, but running the script I get:

> semantic error: while resolving probe point: identifier 'perf' at perf.stp:14:7
>           source: probe perf.hw.instructions.module(MODULE_NAME).counter("find_insns") {}

Any ideas what might be wrong?

**Edit:**

Okay, I realized that the perf counters could be bound to processes only not to modules (Explained here: https://sourceware.org/systemtap/man/stapprobes.3stap.html). Therefore I changed it back to:

```
probe perf.hw.cache_references.process(PATH_TO_BINARY).counter("find_insns") {}
```

Now, as the sample script suggests, I have:

```
probe module(MODULE_NAME).function(FUNC_NAME) {
#save counter values on entrance
...
}
```

But now running it, I get:

> semantic error: perf counter 'find_insns' not defined semantic error:
>   while resolving probe point: identifier 'module' at perf.stp:26:7
>           source: probe module(MODULE_NAME).function(FUNC_NAME)

**Edit2:**

So here is my complete script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env stap

# Usage: stap perf.stp <path-to-binary> <module-name> <function-name>

global cycles_per_insn
global branch_per_insn
global cacheref_per_insn
global insns
global cycles
global branches
global cacherefs
global insn
global cachemisses
global miss_per_insn

probe perf.hw.instructions.process(@1).counter("find_insns") {} 
probe perf.hw.cpu_cycles.process(@1).counter("find_cycles") {} 
probe perf.hw.branch_instructions.process(@1).counter("find_branches") {} 
probe perf.hw.cache_references.process(@1).counter("find_cache_refs") {} 
probe perf.hw.cache_misses.process(@1).counter("find_cache_misses") {}


probe module(@2).function(@3)
{
 insn["find_insns"] = @perf("find_insns")
 insns <<< (insn["find_insns"])
 insn["find_cycles"] = @perf("find_cycles")
 cycles <<< insn["find_cycles"]
 insn["find_branches"] = @perf("find_branches")
 branches <<< insn["find_branches"]
 insn["find_cache_refs"] = @perf("find_cache_refs")
 cacherefs <<< insn["find_cache_refs"]
 insn["find_cache_misses"] = @perf("find_cache_misses")
 cachemisses <<< insn["find_cache_misses"]
}


probe module(@2).function(@3).return 
{
    dividend = (@perf("find_cycles") - insn["find_cycles"])
    divisor =  (@perf("find_insns") - insn["find_insns"])
    q = dividend / divisor
    if (q > 0)
    cycles_per_insn <<< q

    dividend = (@perf("find_branches") - insn["find_branches"])
    q = dividend / divisor
    if (q > 0)
    branch_per_insn <<< q

    dividend = (@perf("find_cycles") - insn["find_cycles"])
    q = dividend / divisor
    if (q > 0)
    cacheref_per_insn <<< q

    dividend = (@perf("find_cache_misses") - insn["find_cache_misses"])
    q = dividend / divisor
    if (q > 0)
        miss_per_insn <<< q
}

probe end
{
 if (@count(cycles_per_insn)) {
   printf ("Cycles per Insn\n\n")
   print (@hist_log(cycles_per_insn))
 }
 if (@count(branch_per_insn)) {
   printf ("\nBranches per Insn\n\n")
   print (@hist_log(branch_per_insn))
 }
 if (@count(cacheref_per_insn)) {
   printf ("Cache Refs per Insn\n\n")
   print (@hist_log(cacheref_per_insn))
 }
 if (@count(miss_per_insn)) {
   printf ("Cache Misses per Insn\n\n")
   print (@hist_log(miss_per_insn))
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Systemtap can't read hardware perfctr values for kernel probes, because linux doesn't provide a suitable (e.g., atomic) internal API for safely reading those values from all contexts.  The perf...process probes work only because that context is not atomic: the systemtap probe handler can block safely.

I cannot answer your detailed question about the two (?) scripts you last experimented with, because they're not complete.

Comment: I added my complete script. Thanks for your help!

Comment: OK, with the fuller script I see the same thing.  Indeed, systemtap cannot resolve @perf() constructs to read perf counter values within module probes, for the reasons stated above.